# Decimal seperators

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress site and I'm doing it with the site language as Swedish. The problem is that in Sweden the default decimal seperator is a comma (eg 1,00) while in English it's a dot (eg 1.00).

I need to make my decimal seperators dots instead of commas while still keeping Swedish as site language.

I am using the latest version of Wordpress and if you need to know any additional info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

number_format will achieve this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$n = 1234.5678;
echo number_format ( $n , 2 , "." , "" ); // 1234.57
echo number_format ( $n , 2 , "," , "" ); // 1234,57
```